# Where to find magento2-sample repository with payment module and many others as examples?

Tags: magento2, module, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway

There is no [sample-module-payment-gateway](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway) to start by developing a custom payment gateway. And, in fact, there is no more [magento2-samples](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/) repository, which made the developers life much easier.

Where samples of modules can be found now?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about sample modules. But for developing your own payment module Magento provides good documentation in the dev docs:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/payments-integrations/base-integration/integration-intro.html

Comment: Thanks, Kristoffer!
I followed this one. It is not enough to complete a working solution.